# Variable number of Inputs for the Function - R

Tags: r

I have the following function that `A` and `B` indicate vector as inputs. My question is how I can have different number of vetors for this function. In my function, `n` is fixed and shows the number of samples. For example, I need that my function works for this case as well: `sample_sum (A, B, C, D, E, n, ...)`.
Also for the part that I get samples of vector A and B (i.e. in line`sample_A <- qss(A, n=n, ...)`) how I can modify it for different number of vectors not using `for` loop since `for` loop is not fast enough.

Thanks

```
sample_sum <- function(A, B, n, ...)
{
  qss <- function(X, n, ...)
  {
    r_X <- range(X)
    dens_X <- density(X, ...)
    sample(dens_X$x, size=n, prob=dens_X$y, replace=TRUE)
  }
sample_A <- qss(A, n=n, ...)
sample_B <- qss(B, n=n, ...)
sample_A + sample_B
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply use a list of vectors for your input? It's not quite what you ask for but it would really simply serve the purpose. What numbers of vectors do you expect, that you conclude, that loops would not be fast enough to handle them? That is likely to be premature optimization.

Comment: @Bernhard, Thanks for your hints. You mean, I replaced  A, B,..vectors with a list and also for "sample" part i use a loop? May you provide your hints as script? Thanks

Comment: Meanwhile, this seems to be already provided by User2321. He did not use a loop but `apply` but that is only a minor difference. Loops are often easier to read for novices and `apply`s for advanced programmers but in terms of speed it does not make that much of a difference in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is the following:

```
new_sample_sum <- function(my_vector_list, n, ...)
{
  qss <- function(X, n, ...)
  {
    r_X <- range(X)
    dens_X <- density(X, ...)
    sample(dens_X$x, size=n, prob=dens_X$y, replace=TRUE)
  }

  rowSums(sapply(my_vector_list, qss, n = n))

}
```

You can put multiple vectors **in your vector list** and then do your calculations over the list without worrying about the number of vectors. Just a brief note on the calculations, sapply will loop over all vectors in the list and then return a **table** with all the results of applying qss to each vector (For every vector the result is one column in the table that sapply returns). Since you add the vectors in the final step of your function I do a rowSums of the table with all the results.

And in order to prove the consistency:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(6,7,9,0)
z <- c(2,2,2,2)

> sample_sum(x, y, n=2)
[1]  6.545129 13.474390

> new_sample_sum(list(x, y), n = 2)
[1]  6.545129 13.474390
```

Or with more vectors:

```
sample_sum <- function(A, B, C, n, ...)
{
  qss <- function(X, n, ...)
  {
    r_X <- range(X)
    dens_X <- density(X, ...)
    sample(dens_X$x, size=n, prob=dens_X$y, replace=TRUE)
  }
  sample_A <- qss(A, n=n, ...)
  sample_B <- qss(B, n=n, ...)
  sample_C <- qss(C, n=n, ...)
  sample_A + sample_B + sample_C
}

set.seed(1)
> sample_sum(x, y, z, n = 2)
[1]  6.102482 15.450364
set.seed(1)
> new_sample_sum(list(x, y, z), n = 2)
[1]  6.102482 15.450364
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `n=length(A)` to dynamically determine the size of the vector arguments.

Comment: I guess that you misunderstood my question. I do not want to get the length of a vector, I need to have different number of vectors as input for the function

Comment: I understood that. My answer is for the second part of your question.